# Java Spring Boot application doesn't run from IDEA due to kotlin error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a Java Spring Boot application which is coded purely in Java. When I try to run it from Intellij IDEA using run configuration, I get the following error:

`Error:Kotlin: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16.`

If I remove build step from run configuration, build using mvn clean install and then run the application, everything works fine.

I have tried changing Kotlin compiler settings in IDEA but the issue persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with running a spring boot application. For me pdating my IDEA to the most recent version (2021.1.1 Ultimate Edition) solved this issue with Kotlin for me.

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Comment: Upgrading worked for me as well. In my case our Java-only application spontaneously became Kotlin when a certain code file was deleted, despite being entirely unrelated. Very reproducible. Something in the internals of IntelliJ was confused and upgrading it un-confused it.

Answer (score 11):

Intellij settings -> languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin -> change Update Channel to a new version

Answer (score 2):

intellij > preferences > plugins > Installed : "uncheck bundled kotlin"